# Double click .csproj opens up the entire sln it is part of

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

I used to be able to do this before-- open a project by double clicking on the .csproj in VS 2008. Now all it does is open the entire solution file it is part of. That is not the intended behavior. I also tried Open->Project from VS2008 and still the same result. I do have Resharper 5.1 installed but there seems to be no such option to open solution instead of project. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If I recall correctly it always opens the solution. Or creates a new solution when the project doesn't belong to one.

Comment: I second PoweRoy. I don't think, you were able to do this before, because this behavior has been around at least since VS2008.

Comment: That's *definitely* by-design. If there's a solution associated with that project, it will open the entire solution.

Comment: if im not mistaken theres an option to not SHOW/NOT SHOW the solution node in the solution explorer, so maybe this is what you experienced, and so thought there was no solution file.

Comment: I think the OP *always* wants to have a new solution created in that particular situation, even when the project belongs to a solution: double-click solution = open solution, double-click project = open project (in created and otherwise empty solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by-design, and I found no command line switches to override that behaviour.

**But** you can work around it, knowing that when you open a project file, it just searches the project file's folder and its parent folder (in that order) for a solution file referencing the project file.
–> If no such solution is found, however, a blank solution is used to open the project!

Comment: This is what worked for me. Create a empty project (a new solution gets created as a side effect). Now add the existing project to this solution.

Comment: Maybe it's too far-fetched, but I suppose one could find a way to associate .csproj files to e.g. a script that 1) renames the .sln files in the 2 folders, 2) then fires up devenv for the project, and 3) renames the .sln files to their original names. This way, you can leave the solutions and projects as they are, and you can decide whether to open the solutions or just the projects and get your desired behaviour :]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could see, this is default behavior of Visual Studio both 2008 and 2010, and even probably 2005. I have this without ReSharper being installed.